# How to run `source_gen`?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am currently trying to use [`built_value`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/built_value) in my Flutter project but I am confused on what I need to do...

I put the following lines in my `pubspec.yaml` (copied from an example project):

```
dev_dependencies:
  build: ^0.7.0
  build_runner: ^0.3.0
  built_value_generator: ^1.0.0
```

But, so far, nothing is happening... In [this video demonstration](https://youtu.be/TMeJxWltoVo?t=735) you can see that the generated code is updated/regenerated on the fly, while the developer is changing his code.

Do I need to do anything else to have the code generation work? Start some kind of server that watches for changes and trigger code generation? Register `source_gen` to be run at some point?

**EDIT:** OK, so now I have a `tool` folder next to the `lib` folder. The `tool` folder contains both `build.dart` and `watch.dart`, both changed to match the package `name:` in my `pubspec.yaml`. The `lib` folder contains a file `user.dart`, which I copied from [this tutorial](https://medium.com/dartlang/darts-built-value-for-immutable-object-models-83e2497922d4).

```
library user;

import 'package:built_value/built_value.dart';

part 'user.g.dart';

abstract class User implements Built<User, UserBuilder> {
  String get name;

  @nullable
  String get nickname;

  User._();

  factory User([updates(UserBuilder b)]) = _$User;
}
```

Shouldn't I now be seeing a `user.g.dart` file appear in `lib` that contains the generated code? There's nothing wrong with the glob pattern, is it?

**EDIT 2:** This is the output of `flutter --version`:

```
dmta@elite:~/flutter$ flutter --version
Flutter • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision e65d47d4ba (11 hours ago) • 2017-05-15 12:40:20 -0700
Engine • revision 7dd359e165
Tools • Dart 1.23.0-dev.11.11
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a file `tool/build.dart` like, to generate the model classes

> ```
> // Copyright (c) 2016, Google Inc. Please see the AUTHORS file for details.
> // All rights reserved. Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style
> // license that can be found in the LICENSE file.
>
> import 'dart:async';
>
> import 'package:build_runner/build_runner.dart';
> import 'package:built_value_generator/built_value_generator.dart';
> import 'package:source_gen/source_gen.dart';
>
> /// Build the generated files in the built_value chat example.
> Future main(List<String> args) async {
>   await build(
>       new PhaseGroup.singleAction(
>           new GeneratorBuilder([
>             new BuiltValueGenerator(),
>           ]),
>           new InputSet('chat_example', const ['lib/**/*.dart'])),
>       deleteFilesByDefault: true);
> }
> ```

or a `watch.dart` file like also shown in https://github.com/google/built_value.dart/tree/master/chat_example/tool that watches for changes in the source files and regenerates the `built_value` model classes whenever one of the source files was modified.

Comment: Thanks, but I am afraid I am still missing something - the `tool` folder goes next to `lib`, right? And the first parameter of `InputSet` is the package name that I set with `name: my_package_name` in `pubspec.yaml`?

Comment: Was away. Yes, that's right. And `'lib/**/*.dart'` are the files `built_value` classes are generated for.

Comment: Sure, no problem! Still, nothing's happening here... If you have time, please look at my updated question... Thanks!

Comment: Can you please try to move the `user.dart` file into a sub-directory of `lib` like `lib/model/user.dart` and run `dart tool/build.dart` again?

Comment: OK, when I am running these commands, I am getting `'package:source_gen/src/utils.dart': error: line 56 pos 1: unexpected token 'Iterable'
Iterable<T> safeIterate<T>(Iterable<T> iterable, void onError(e, st)) sync* {
^` in both cases... The location of `user.dart` does not seem to make any difference for this...

Comment: So maybe `source_gen` _was_ running all along, but did not produce any output because it crashed?

Comment: I guess you're using a Dart version that doesn't yet support generic methods. Can you please post the output of `flutter --version`?

Comment: I usually try to pull Flutter every day before doing anything with it - would that also update dart? In any case I am on `1.23.0-dev.11.11` which seems quite current. For the full output see my updated question.

Comment: I saw it mentioned a few times recently that it is planned to get to a newer Dart version with Flutter but that it was blocked on something but that it is expected to be ready within about a week. Dart 1.23.0 stable is out already and generic methods is quite a new feature. Can you please check in the `pubspec.lock` file what `source_gen` version is actually used in your project? You can also try to add `source_gen: 0.5.4+3` to force an older version.

Comment: Oh, wait - it seems I also had the Dart SDK 1.19 installed. So Flutter has its own version of Dart? I've now updated The Dart SDK to 1.23 and put `user.dart` back into `lib/model`... When I now run `dart tool/build.dart`, the `user.g.dart` seems to be generated correctly, but only from the command line. Editing the file in IntelliJ does not have any effect...

Comment: For editing to have any effect `watch.dart` needs to be running in the background. Yes Flutter has its own Dart SDK included and it's a bit different from the normal server-side Dart SDK.

Comment: `source_gen` is version `0.5.5` according to `pubspec.lock`

Comment: @david.mihola the `source_gen` version shouldn't matter anymore if you were running on 1.19 and are now on 1.23.

Comment: Ah, OK, so when I am starting `dart tool/watch.dart` from the command line and leave it running it does actually generate the updates. Is there any way to do this from within IntelliJ? Sorry for my ignorance - I somehow expected IntelliJ to know it should run the stuff from the `tool` folder...

Comment: I haven't tried but perhaps https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/using-file-watchers.html can help. I don't know if the watchers need to specially support IntelliJ or if any runnable application or script can be used.

Comment: OK, I'll look into that... but running from the command line is perfectly fine for now! Nochmals vielen Dank aus Wien nach Linz!

Comment: @david.mihola :D freut mich dass ich auch wieder mal einem Landsmann behilflich sein kann. Viel Spass mit Dart!

Comment: Is modifying a class possible with source gen? Or only creating new class?